# Android AlarmClock() , setting alarm date

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I am having trouble with setting a specific date to AlarmClock() rather than AlarmManager(). All the example I am having over internet shows to start an activity at a specific date using AlarmManager(). but my app dosent have / need a custom activity. I only need to register a system alarm on a specific day where it will ring like generic android system alarm.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Polo!");
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 1);
context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
```

above is my code. I tried to use

```
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

but it only takes the current day.

Please help me setting alarm using the AlarmClock() on a specific day.

Comment: "cannot resolve symbol" @VishalChhodwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

> EXTRA_DAYS (optional): Weekdays for repeating alarm.

So actually, AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS is for days in week when this alarm should ring, so you can't set exact date for the alarm. Example usage:

```
ArrayList<Integer> days = new ArrayList<Integer>();
days.add(Calendar.SATURDAY);
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, days);
```

Comment: Tried and Failed, It seems from android developer portal that EXTRA_DAYS features week days not actually date of the month like 28th of March https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#EXTRA_DAYS  can you please help me choosing the correct parameter??

Comment: updated my answer - I believe you can't set alarm for exact date using AlarmClock

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Calendar.getInstance()` will return a `Calendar` object initialized with the current date. You need to set the `Calendar` object to the desired date and then access its fields, for example:

```
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30)
```

then when you call

```
c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

it returns 30. Otherwise, it returns the current date.

Comment: surprizingly not working, tried your advise above and alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));  it registers the current day. alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS,30); also shows no warning in the IDE but still it sets the current day

Comment: EXTRA_DAYS
added in API level 19
String EXTRA_DAYS
Bundle extra: Weekdays for repeating alarm.

Used by ACTION_SET_ALARM.

The value is an ArrayList<Integer>. Each item can be:

SUNDAY,
MONDAY,
TUESDAY,
WEDNESDAY,
THURSDAY,
FRIDAY,
SATURDAY

Comment: It seems that from the developers website that Extra_DAYS takes the weekday not date !!!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#EXTRA_DAYS   can you please have a quick look and let me choose the exact parametr I need, my study concludes that there is no method to set a date , but I can set a alarm date If I try operating in the phon in my hand, is it the ACTION_SET_TIMER ? I am confused.